# printf only prints characters up to stdout's buffer size

Tags: c, newlib

I'm trying to use newlib's printf function to print something on a UART device. Therefor I implemented

```
int _write(int file, char *ptr, int len) {
  HAL_StatusTypeDef status;

  switch (file) {
  case STDOUT_FILENO: /*stdout*/
  case STDERR_FILENO: /* stderr */
    while ((status = HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&UART_Uart2Handle, ptr, len)) == HAL_BUSY) {}

    if (status != HAL_ERROR) {
      errno = EBADF;
      return -1;
    }
    break;
  default:
    errno = EBADF;
    return -1;
  }
  return len;
}
```

Printing works fine until the buffer of stdout is filled, e.g. if I try

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOFBF, 3);
printf("Hello World!\n");
fflush(stdout); // Just to be sure ;)
```

I only receive a 'Hel' on the device. A similar behaviour is observed with `_IONBF` or `_IOLBF`. When I set a breakpoint on `_write` in the debugger I gets called only once for the content of one buffer size.

Any ideas or hints why `_write` does not get called more often?

Comment: Useful? [HAL_UART_Transmit_IT: only a few bytes are sent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33429920/2410359)

Comment: It appears `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()` does not report how many characters were transmitted so try 1 at a time.  Instead repeatable try to send 1 character when result is `HAL_BUSY`, else then move on to the next character.

Comment: I see the same behaviour if I use HAL_UART_Transmit instead and also when transmitting one character at a time. Problem seems to be that _write only gets called once.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that `_write` always returned `-1` as `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT` returns `HAL_OK` when everything went fine, so

```
if (status != HAL_ERROR) {
      errno = EBADF;
      return -1;
}
```

was always executed. The check needs to be changed to `status != HAL_OK`.